# Averaging values that fall within specific date ranges?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2012

I'm working on writing a query that should take values that fall within specific datetime ranges and spit out their average. However, I'm running into some hiccups.

Essentially, I have a large dataset that has multiple different subsets of data spread out over 30 days. I need to figure out how to average the values from across 2 days from 9am-9am.

An example of my dataset:

```
Device1     Values      TimeFrame
---------------------------------------------------------           
Device1     Value1      2016-03-27 00:03:11.000 0.0019
Device1     Value2      2016-03-27 00:03:11.000 18.7041
Device1     Value3      2016-03-27 00:03:11.000 49.5902
Device1     Value1      2016-03-27 00:08:06.000 0.0019
Device1     Value2      2016-03-27 00:08:06.000 18.7041
Device1     Value3      2016-03-27 00:08:06.000 49.5902
Device1     Value1      2016-03-27 00:13:09.000 0.0019
Device1     Value2      2016-03-27 00:13:09.000 18.7041
Device1     Value3      2016-03-27 00:13:09.000 49.5902
Device1     Value1      2016-03-28 00:03:11.000 0.0019
Device1     Value2      2016-03-28 00:03:11.000 18.7041
Device1     Value3      2016-03-28 00:03:11.000 49.5902
Device1     Value1      2016-03-28 00:08:06.000 0.0019
Device1     Value2      2016-03-28 00:08:06.000 18.7041
Device1     Value3      2016-03-28 00:08:06.000 49.5902
Device1     Value1      2016-03-28 00:13:09.000 0.0019
Device1     Value2      2016-03-28 00:13:09.000 18.7041
Device1     Value3      2016-03-28 00:13:09.000 49.5902
```

I need to calculate the averages for each value for each day, but with the assumption that the day STARTS at 9am and ends at 9am the next day. It's a bit wonky. I'm not quite sure where to even start here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do this by subtracting 9 hours and using `group by`:

```
select cast(dateadd(hour, -9, timeframe) as date) as thedate,
       count(*) as num, avg(value) as avg_value
from dataset t
group by cast(dateadd(hour, -9, timeframe) as date)
order by thedate;
```